# Cant select from a dynamic dropdown field

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have been trying to select from a list streets dropdown options in a field but the problem is the list of dropdowns depend on another field that takes zipcode as an input, so basically every zipcode and its list of dropdowns. how do i go about this please.
These are examples of zipcodes i use for testing:  [97074, 97491, 97488].
The site is in German but the label of the zipcode field is "Mein Haushalt befindet sich in"
url = https://www.allianz.de/recht-und-eigentum/hausratversicherung/rechner/

my code below:

```
 public void selectStreetOption(By locator, String streetOption) {
        WebElement streetDropdown = driver.findElement(locator);
        Select streetSelect = new Select(streetDropdown);
        streetSelect.selectByVisibleText(streetOption);
    }
```

Comment: Update the question with your code trials.

Answer (score 0):

I have answered the question, after no response i had to take it step by step approach and finally landed on this.

```
public void clickStreet(By locator, String text) throws InterruptedException {
        int counter = 0;
        driver.findElement(locator).click();
        sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@class,'nx-dropdown__filter-input')]")).sendKeys(text);
        sleep(2000);
        List<WebElement> suggestList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'nx-dropdown-results__option')]"));
        for(WebElement street : suggestList){
            String streetInput = street.getText();
            if(streetInput.contains(text)){
                street.click();
                counter++;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(counter!=0){
            System.out.println(text + "has been selected");
        }else{
            System.out.println("The option you provided is not available");
        }
    }
```